# What can be causing output voltage to drop on LT1763 with very little load?

Tags: voltage-regulator

On a breadboard, I am using an LT1763 5V regulator connected as per the "Typical Application" diagram on page one of the datasheet ([LT1763 DataSheet](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/1763fg.pdf)).  From a benchtop power supply I give 12V at the input and measure a steady 5.011V on the output.

Now, if I add a 10K resistor between the output and ground (which should only draw 0.5mA), the output voltage sinks to around 4.8V. I put an ammeter on the input line and can see that the regulator is only drawing well less than 1mA.  This regulator is rated to 500mA.

I swapped out a 3.3V regulator and see similar behaviour (output voltage drops to well below 3V with the resistor applied). I moved around to another location on the breadboard and still the same.  Checked all the capacitors on my Fluke and they are all good. Tried different input voltages from 6-15V and the behaviour is the same.

There is nothing else connected to this regulator and I am completely stumped.

Any ideas as to what I am missing and why the voltage could be dropping so much?

Comment: Look at Vout with an oscilloscope. Oscillations (sometimes rail to rail) can occur and cause apparent_DC  Vout to vary widely. Are you meeting this spec: "The LT1763 regulators are stable with output
capacitors as low as 3.3μF. Small ceramic capacitors can
be used without the series resistance required by other
regulators." ie what is Cout value? || See Fig 3 page 15. Cout >= 6 uF for very low ESR. (dEEP-ENDS ON cBYP).

Comment: Is this fixed or adjustable version?

Comment: This is fixed.  5V and 3.3V behave the same.  I am going to check it on the oscilloscope.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It could be oscillating. It's difficult to ensure short connections unless a PCB is used.

Comment: I looked on the scope and it was oscillating, with a mean voltage around what I was measuring.  The amplitude of the oscillation was much higher with lower resistance and almost none with a 1M resistor.  Up to that point, I was only powering other IC's.  This problem started when I added some 10K pullups on some digital outputs.  Guess these are not to good on a breadboard with long leads.   Will just grab a 7805 instead.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe useful for future users,  your device is perhaps not stable due to the capacitors. The output capacitor max ESR is 3.0 Ohm, and for the minimum ESR are also criteria for stability (see datasheet).

In my case the device was also not stable, when I removed the bypass capacitor the device worked properly. The output capacitor I used had a very low ESR, so perhaps one capacitor with a higher ESR would work better.

Comment: can you also give citation of source of the information or logical explanation please?

Answer (score 0):

Many regulators (linear and switching) have minimum load requirements.  If your load is lighter than the minimum then output voltage regulation is not guaranteed.

I cannot find anything in the LT1763 datasheet that specifies a minimum load, but that is not a guarantee that this isn't an issue.  Try putting a 10+ mA load on it and see what happens.

If that isn't the problem then you probably hooked it up wrong.

Comment: Tried a smaller resistor and got a huge drop...going back to recheck everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a 5V fixed regulator, pin 2 (SENSE) should be tied to the output.  Do you have the SHUTDWN pin tied to Vin?  I doubt you need a min load current.

Do you still have the ammeter hooked up on the VIN side?  If so, is the input cap tied directly to the Vin pin?  If not then the ammeter's finite impedance is maybe messin with you and causing oscillation. That 1uF input cap is an important source of charge that needs to be close to the Vin pin.  Take the ammeter out (flying leads, inductive). Make sure all the traces (or lead lengths) are short.  If you still have problems, I would go back to the starting setup, which is the bench supply, no ammeter, no load.